# Hide Toolbar with Coordinator layout and RecyclerView in a fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I have searched but no questions here solved my problem. I want to achieve the common behaviour, but I only get that:

[image: my_behaviour]

Here is my MainActivity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
tools:context="es.dmoral.tinylist.fragments.SavedListsFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/saved_list_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

One solution I've found is updating the appcompat and recyclerview libraries, but I have the last versions (23.1.1) so I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved changing

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
```